# How get specific Field data by document id from firestore website

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
  auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user){

if(user.uid){
    var db = firebase.firestore();


   document.getElementById("empUpd_email").value = user.email;
    


  db.collection("employee").doc(user.uid).get().then(result => {
        console.log(`${result.id} => ${result.data()}`);
```

document.getElementById('empUpd_fullname').value=result.fullName;

```
});
  
  
}else{
  
 
  //no user is signed in
}
});**strong text**
```

i wanna gender value how i get it

> And Database looks like

address
"abdul"
(string)
bio
"abdul"
dob
"2020-08-22"
fullName
"abdul"
gender
"Female"
serName
"abdul"

Comment: Can you share the sample data stored in the database or a screenshot of a database structure ?.

Comment: @ShriHari check now

Comment: check out my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can just retrieve the value of `gender`, using the same way how you did it for `fullName`. 
Try something like this,

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

  if (user.uid) {
    var db = firebase.firestore();
    document.getElementById("empUpd_email").value = user.email;
    db.collection("employee").doc(user.uid).get().then((result) => {
      const results = result.data(); 
      document.getElementById('empUpd_fullname').value = results.fullName;
      document.getElementById('empUpd_gender').value = results.gender; // Tag ID is a guess!
    });
  } else {
    //no user is signed in
  }
});
```

Hope that works!

Answer (score 0):

```
DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("User").document(Objects.requireNonNull(fAuth.getCurrentUser()).getUid());
        documentReference.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                    profileName.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Name"));
                    profileEmail.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Email"));
                }
            }
        });
```